# close the form from mdi parent when i click to open any other form

Tags: c#

i have a mdi form and there is lot of other form linked with the menu strip. when i click any other menu item then there should be close previous open form inside the mdi parent form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this method when you want to open a new form:

```
private void CloseAllForms()
{
    Form[] formToClose = null;
    int i = 1;
    foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (form != this) //this is form1
        {
            Array.Resize(ref formToClose, i);
            formToClose[i - 1] = form;
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (formToClose != null)
        for (int j = 0; j < formToClose.Length; j++)
            formToClose[j].Dispose();
}
```

Mitja

Comment: `Array.Resize` really? Use a dynamically sized container like `List<Form>`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more succinct, modern, and surgical way to close all MdiChild forms:

```
static void CloseAllMdiChildForms()
{
    foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Where(f => f.IsMdiChild).ToArray()) // ToArray necessary to build a snapshot
        form.Close();
}
```

However, it sounds like what you want is to have only one child form open at any given time. If that is the case, MDI is not the right tool for the job. You can build `UserControl`s and swap them into and out of your main application form instead.

Comment: see i have a administrator form and in this form lot of menu items and all opens a new form. but open a new from and when again i will open a new from then new form will be open but old will not be close.there many form open in administrator form. i wand when i open any form on click a menu item the other form should be close.

Comment: @vivek: It's not clear to me exactly what your requirement is, but there is no magic in the click handlers for menu items. You have to write the code that executes there, so you can do anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is best one:

```
static void CloseAllMdiChildForms()
{
    foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Where(f => f.IsMdiChild).ToArray()) // The ToArray is necessary to build a snapshot
    form.Close();
}
```