# close the form from mdi parent when i click to open any other form

Tags: c#

i have an administrator form and in this form lot of menu items and all open a new form. but when I open a new from again i will open a new from then new form will be open but old form will not be closed.there are many form open in administrator form. i wand when i open any form on click a menu item the other form close.

Comment: possible duplicate of [close the form from mdi parent when i click to open any other form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442297/close-the-form-from-mdi-parent-when-i-click-to-open-any-other-form)

Comment: Repeating the same question and expecting a different answer is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you have to know each form object then you can close it, for example when you want to open one windows you write

```
new MyForm().ShowDialog();
```

Ok instead you can declare a form object in the top of your administrator form:

```
Form oldForm;
```

when user press one of your forms list:

```
if (oldForm != null)
   oldForm.Close();
Form newOne = new UsersForm();
oldForm = newOne; 
newOne.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: oh DDD i was trying in place of newOne.ShowDialog                  frm.MdiParent = this;
frm.Show();                                                            but when a new form is open then previous form gone be close but new form is not coming on exact position its position is not as a fix position..

Comment: I don't understand ? However, If you want, you can open one form only at time, and prevent user from opening another by using form.ShowDialog(this);  instead of form.Show(); if the user clicks one button on AdministartorForm, a dialog appears, and user can't click another button until he closes the previous one. I think this is much better for you.